Expo-Font not loading on subscreens
Im using Expo and Expo-font. And im using the dev-apk feature from expo. So im NOT using Expo-Go.
So now to my problem. Im using Expo font in my /src/app/_layout.tsx and rendering all the fonts there.
It works for the _layout.tsx, so i can use the fonts there but nowhere else.
As an example if i try to use it in /src/app/(auth)/signin.tsx its not working.
/app/_layout.tsx
import {
      DarkTheme,
      DefaultTheme,
      ThemeProvider,
    } from "@react-navigation/native";
    import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
    import { Stack } from "expo-router";
    import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { Session } from "@supabase/supabase-js";

    import { useColorScheme } from "@components/useColorScheme";
    import AuthProvider from "@/providers/AuthProvider";
    import { FontProvider } from "@/providers/FontProvider";

    export {
      // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
      ErrorBoundary,
    } from "expo-router";

    export const unstable_settings = {
      // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
      initialRouteName: "(tabs)",
    };

    // Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
    SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

    export default function RootLayout() {
      const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
        MontserratBlack: require("../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Black.ttf"),
        MontserratBold: require("../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf"),
        MontserratExtraBold: require("../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-ExtraBold.ttf"),
        MontserratMedium: require("../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf"),
        MontserratRegular: require("../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf"),
        MontserratSemiBold: require("../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf"),
      });

      // Expo Router uses Error Boundaries to catch errors in the navigation tree.
       useEffect(() => {
         if (error) throw error;
      }, [error]);

      useEffect(() => {
        if (loaded) {
          SplashScreen.hideAsync();
        }
      }, [loaded]);

      if (!loaded) {
        return null;
      }

      return <RootLayoutNav />;
    }

    function RootLayoutNav() {
      const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

      return (
        <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
          <AuthProvider>
              <Stack>
                <Stack.Screen name="(auth)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
              </Stack>
          </AuthProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      );
    }

And /src/app/(auth)/signup.tsx
import React from "react";
    import { View, Text } from "react-native";
    import { Link } from "expo-router";

    const Signup = () => {
      return (
         <View>
          <Text style={{ fontFamily: "MontserratBold" }}>Signup</Text>
          <Link href="/(auth)/signin">Back</Link>
        </View>
      );
    };

    export default Signup;

Its not showing the font in signup.
But if i change the layout and only use a  component which i style to montserrat it works.
Ive already tried:
-Rebuilding the App throught expo and reinstalling it in my emulator
-using react-link
-importing the fonts directly into the component/screen
Im expecting, that i can use my fonts everywhere, no matter which screen im in.
